# Histogram of linear data

Tags: r

I'm doing some experiments on histograms of image data. At a first step I tried to make a linear vector with values from 0 to 255. When printing the histogram of this vector I'd assume that every value would have the same frequency. But the `hist`function returns histograms where 0 has a higher frequency and 255 a lower than other values. Even when choosing a different bin size...

What am I doing wrong?

```
rampImageData<-rep(rep(0:255, each=4), each=512)
hist(rampImageData)
```

[image]

Comment: Try to simplify your lines of code as much as possible.  Then read `help(breaks)` carefully, and you will discover how to understand what are you doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to "binning".

Look:

```
library(ggplot2)
```

"Unexpected" behaviour for a Uniform:

```
qplot(rampImageData, geom = 'histogram') # default bins = 30
```

[image]

"Expected" behaviour for a Uniform:

```
qplot(rampImageData, geom = 'histogram', bins = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that explains it!